# How to configure router

Tags: networking

[image]

I am configuring this network diagram. But i cannot configure ip add for the interface connecting the router which is Fa0/0/0 to Fa0/0/3. This caused me not able to ping from a subnet to another one. I can ping inside each subnet. i connect everything using a straight through cable. i am not sure if its my network address that goes wrong or anything else. i wanna ask how do i configure ip add to the interfaces of the router and do i need to insert routing command such as RIP for this network diagram.

Comment: Welcome to SU. This is a bit confusing. Firstly, in this scenario you must use network prefix /28; i.e. subnet mask 255.255.255.240 in all networks. `Fa0/0/0` and `Fa00/0/3` are on the same router. `/0` must have an IP in range 192.168.0.1-14, `/3` in range 192.168.0.17-30. Can you please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1771663/edit) the question and clarify which interface you have problems with? Please copy-paste from the router CLI the exact commands you use to configure it, with the  exact router responses. Enclose commands and outputs in code brackets `{ }` to preserve formatting.

Comment: `not able to ping from a subnet to another one. I can ping inside each subnet` Do the PCs and friends have (correct) default gateway set?